# Broken fonts in new frames

Tags: faces, frames, fonts

In new frames opened by C-x 5 2, the text appears as rectangles (see the gif below). Possibly, Emacs doesn't respect my font settings. In my init.el file, I have the following lines:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil
                    :family "Source Code Pro"
                    :foundry "unknown"
                    :height 180 :width 'normal :weight 'normal :slant 'normal)
```

How can I fix this issue?

[image: Broken font]

Comment: Try to see if you can select the font from the menu-bar with your mouse. If not, Emacs can't find it. This means you probably didn't install the font correctly.

Comment: @shynur, you're right—the Source Code Pro font is missing. Thank you! However, now I don't understand why Emacs uses a fallback font for the first frame but doesn't use it for new frames.

Comment: That might be a good question to ask on the `gnu.emacs.help` mailing list. I suspect that Emacs wants to respect your font settings, but tries to not cripple itself completely if e.g. the chosen font is not installed, thus giving you a chance to debug the situation. What font does it choose to fall back to in the first frame?